# Sum of all the residues of the function $a(z)/b(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, residue-calculus

Let $a(z)$ and $b(z)$ be polynomials such that
$ \deg(b) \ge \deg(a)+2$.

Find the sum of all the residues of the function $a(z)/b(z)$.

In class, I learned that

$$
- \text{ sum of all residues of }\frac {a(z)}{b(z)}\cdot\log(z) = \int_0^\infty \frac {a(z)}{b(z)}dz
$$

by doing the integration over a circle (setting $R$ approaching infinity) by letting $f(z) = (a(z)/b(z))\cdot\log(z)$. Should I do the same procedure?

Or Is there any other method?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Estimate the result of integrating $a(z)/b(z)$ around a very large circle...